# PHP preg_replace not working when I use { in the substitution

Tags: php, preg-replace

For some reason `preg_replace` is not working when the substitution includes curly braces `{}`.

If the original line is:

```
$Original_Line = "new_Journey('Iceland', {character: 'lidenbrock'}, {author : 'verne', destination : 'snæfellsjökull'})";
```

and the substitution (after pattern matching) is:

```
new_Journey('$1', [$3, $2])
```

giving the following pattern-match/substitution:

```
$Replacement_Line = preg_replace("/new_Journey\(\'([^\']+)\'\,\s*\{([^\}]+)\}\,\s*\{([^\}]+)\}\)\;/", "new_Journey('$1', [$3, $2])", $Original_Line);
```

the output is correct (albeit with square brackets `[]` instead of curly braces `{}`):

```
new_Journey('Iceland', [author : 'verne', destination : 'snæfellsjökull', character: 'lidenbrock']);
```

But if the substution uses curly braces `{}` instead of square brackets `[]` like this:

```
new_Journey('$1', {$3, $2})
```

the output is an error:

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '3' (T_LNUMBER),
>   expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in **[...][...]** on
>   line **5**

Should I be escaping the curly braces `{}` in the substitution? If so, how?

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew can you explain the dup flag here. The unquoted `$2` put it in PHP context in the dup. Quoted it should pass to the PCRE processor as `"$2"` would. This question is specifically about why `"{$2}"` fails to compile. This seem unrelated to me. All of the dup answers go into validity of variable names but if that is the case `"$2"` should also be invalid, which it is not.

Comment: The only problem in this question is the PHP string literal syntax. The rest is not relevant, hence it **is a duplicate**.

Comment: I am still curious as to why the regex backreference in `"[$2]"` is parsed correctly, while in `"{$2}"` it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` must be escaped because PHP is trying to expand the `$3` to a variable but variable names in PHP can't be just numbers.

```
"new_Journey('$1', {\$3, \$2})"
```

Comment: Ah. Got it. Essentially, inside double quotes, PHP cannot discern between a `$` indicating a regex backreference and a `$` indicating a PHP variable. Thanks very much for that clarification.

Comment: @RouninsaysJesuisMonica Well actually no, the `$3` should be valid, it roughly a backreference and is not meant to be a PHP variable. As can be seen here https://3v4l.org/p0EKR outside curlies works fine. Where as https://3v4l.org/F83Fl. This seems to be a PHP error to me. Wish the downvoter would have commented so it could be discussed further. Dup also seems incorrect, `$2` from dup is being used in PHP context, not for the PCRE processor.

Comment: @Rounin There are a lot of duplicates with SQL so I think the dups there are usually useful. However I think one user with super privileges to close is incorrect. 3-5 users should agree on the dup... or 2 users disagreeing should supercede 1 user's close vote, or put it into an appeal process. For future reference I've submitted this as a bug to PHP, can be monitored here, https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79044. I'll update if a solution comes in there, or a explanation of the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces instead of a doubly-quoted string has some explicit uses in PHP, so in your case it might be that PHP thinks that you want to declare a variable when it sees the open curly braces since you can do the following:

```
$var = "bananas";
$test = "{$var} are yummy" // Will execute: bananas are yummy
```

You can replace the whole string to have a single quote and escape `$1` as follows:

```
'new_Journey(\'$1\', {$3, $2})'
```

Since the above explanation do not apply on single quotes.

Comment: Thanks. Good work. Using single quotes (and escaping literal single quotes) is a great alternative approach to using double quotes and escaping `$` signs.